# Change toast notification position windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, toast

How can I change the position of toast notification to be in the upper-left corner?
I try to set the default language to right to left language but no change occure.

Comment: They're already at the top and the text is left justified. How is that different from what you want? Regardless, you don't have any control over how they display, only the contents.

Comment: It seems, you have an option to change it in the Registry. Please follow this URL: http://winaero.com/blog/move-notification-toasts-to-top-or-bottom-of-the-screen-in-windows-10/